# How do you refer to a specific view which was created in a for loop?

Tags: ios, swift

I. I have created a few tableviews in my viewcontroller using a for loop

```
for index in 0...array.count - 1 {

        if let table = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Table", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? Table {

            table.frame.origin.y = 200 * CGFloat(index) + 100

            table.dataSource = self
            table.delegate = self
            table.register(UINib.init(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            table.isScrollEnabled = false

            self.view.addSubview(table)
        }

    }
```

II. Now I want to specify the number of rows for each table separately. Apparently it is done like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of items in the sample data structure.

    var count:Int?

    if tableView == self.tableView {
        count = sampleData.count
    }

    if tableView == self.tableView1 {
        count =  sampleData1.count
    }

    return count!

}
```

The example refers to the two different tableviews using self.tableView and self.tableView1. How can I refer to a specific tableview, which was created in my for loop? They were both created as 'table' and I have not stored them under unique variables.

Comment: You could use a `tag` to differentiate them, or simply keep track of them in an array property if you don't want to keep them in different properties.

Comment: Also - why do you want to have multiple tableviews on a screen? Can’t you accomplish your goal using sections?

Comment: @Larme: How would you refer to them using a tag? I've tried `if tableView == table.tag` but it didn't show tag as an option.

@Losiowaty: Unfortunately I do need multiple tableviews on the viewcontroller

Comment: `for loop { tableView.tag = index }`, delegate/datasource methods: `if tableView.tag == 1 { } else if tableView.tag == n {}`, etc. Be carefull with tag 0, it's the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a property to hold your `Table` instances:

```
var tables: [Table]?
```

Then your routine can populate this array:

```
tables = (0..<array.count).compactMap { index -> Table? in
    guard let table = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Table", owner: self)?.first as? Table else {
        return nil
    }

    table.frame.origin.y = 200 * CGFloat(index) + 100

    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self
    table.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    table.isScrollEnabled = false

    return table
}

tables?.forEach { view.addSubview($0) }
```

Then you can use that array of `tables` in your various data source methods.